# JAX-WS client: JAXB required?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-ws

I need to "dive into JAX-WS programming".

So, I played around with Netbeans, after 20 or so erroneous attempts,
finally managed to let a web service client execute a web service.

I noticed, that a lot of code is generated, especially JAXB classes
for the web service response.

My current task is, to write a web service and web client completely 
by hand.

Is JAXB required at all? Is is part of the standard anyway? What would happen without it?

**EDIT:**
[Seems that the answer is given **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315787/jax-ws-returning-a-complex-object/1315793#1315793)

Comment: Aye, dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300031/jax-ws-client-jaxb-required

Answer (score 0):

You can see [Developing Web Services with Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition (J2EE) 1.4 Platform](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/j2ee_ws/)

Comment: In JavaEE 1.4, there was no JAXB. I assumed that, may be, JAXB was added as mandatory to JavaEE 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I took a wsdl and used eclipse to generate the service, serviceLocator, ws interface, ws binding stub, ws proxy, and then the client code.  I added a main method and was able to hit the webservice successfully.

I used this tutorial as a guide with the url below and no, there are no jaxb objects as I'm not pulling any objects back in the simple example I used.  I was just hitting some methods that pulled back a boolean value.

http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html